# Can I do a "Take(x)" on the "Include" entity in a Linq Query?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, include, projection

i've got a really simple linq to entites statement :-

```
var query = (from q in Users.Include("UserHistory")
            select q).Take(20);
```

works great ... except that, for each user .. the history can be n+1. Some users have 100's of `UserHistory` records.

So, can I restrict the the number of `UserHistory` records to .. 10 or 5 or whatever?

Do I need to use *projections* for this? Can it be done without *projections*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this by using the include, but you can try this:

```
var query =
    from user in Users
    select new
    {
        user, 
        history = user.UserHistory.Take(20) 
    };
```

I'm not sure whether EF is able to create one single SQL query of of it.

Comment: Yep - Alex James (of MS ADO.NET / Linq-To-Sql / EF / OData fame) confirmed this on twitter.